# Issue with sub tree split from main GITHUB repo and creating composer package

Tags: git, laravel, symfony, github, composer-php

The idea is to create a component out of the existing  composer project. I have splited the folder out of main repository and created new repository. 
Using [Reference:](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)

Also registered both the package in packagist. Now when I install the main package using composer command below:

```
composer create-project sanjoydesk/myapp
```

It is not replacing the newly create package into the sub folder. Composer.json available in each repository.

I am trying to create various components out of my main project for my project and I want exactly the same as how Symfony/Laravel components created. 
Any help is highly appreciable.

Reference: 
[Main repository](https://github.com/sanjoydesk/myapp),  [Sub Repository](https://github.com/sanjoydesk/testing-split)

Comment: Hello anyone there to help ?

Answer (score 0):

If "sanjoydesk/myapp" was once the repo also containing the files now residing in "sanjoydesk/testing-split", you should not `"replace": {"sanjoydesk/testing-split": "self.version"}`, because that would tell Composer that "sanjoydesk/myapp" should be counted as the same package as "sanjoydesk/testing-split" (if they are the exact same version).

This will not install "sanjoydesk/testing-split", it will prevent it from being installed, because that package is already there.

You should probably use `"require": {"sanjoydesk/testing-split":"self.version"}` in order to install the split repository, but you should also make sure that any classes that are now pulled via this library are NOT present in "sanjoydesk/myapp". Otherwise you will confuse Composer and yourself where exactly to find a particular class.

Also note that maintaining exact version number synchronicity is a pain, you should probably just require one sufficient version number of "sanjoydesk/testing-split", and not "self.version", and then develop the library independently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not sure if I understand correctly. Let me explain little. In my case "REPO1" which is main repo. It has multiple folder inside sanjoydesk/REPO1/src/MyApp/Folder1, Folder2, Folder3 etc. Now this main repository folders I want to split into separate read only sub repository. Which can be used standalone sub package as well. Now each time i install the main package it should contain the sub package inside it. Can you please help me with this ? Thanks in advance.. @Sven

Comment: Not sure if I understand your expectation correctly, but you may be wrong: If you use/install the main application from it's repo, that repo contains the files that also got extracted into a seperate repo. And your composer file tells the world with "replace" that any depencency on the sub package can be fulfilled by the main package - because it has the files. What do you mean by "It is not replacing the newly create package into the sub folder." in your original question? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Ok let me give you some reference: I want the same as Laravel, Symfony works. Symfony has many different components and which also utilize by its own framework in it. Laravel also was fullstack framework and later on splitted into component which is utilized by framework also. Hope this clear now. I want to do something exactly similar. Or can we chat in facebook or gmail to understand get help .. @Sven

Comment: I know what you want on the general level, but what do you expect to happen in detail? Why should Composer touch anything related to the sub component if it is already installed with the main package?

Comment: Ok. May be I am wrong. So if i am not wrong all changes of any component will be pushed to main repository only (into directories). But do i need to push those changes manually into Sub Repo ? or it will automatically sync my directory code into component repo ? @Sven

Comment: I believe i can understand it better and quickly if we have a short chat. May be over Facebook Or Gmail or Skype or Any other Messenger. Can I have your ID please. Will be great help you please. @Sven

Comment: I found this link explaining how it is (or was) done for Symfony: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-components-as-standalone-packages The description makes me think that repositories do not update themselves automatically. The same is true for tagging the released versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134769/discussion-between-appsntech-and-sven).